# jquery autocomplete trigger by @ symbol

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I need to trigger autocomplete using @ symbol using jquery.
For Instance:
   If i put the '@' symbol then automatically load data into autocomplete box.suppose if i select other symbol not need to load trigger autocomplete.

Comment: What you try so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Dont just ask plain question, share what you have tried also. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533562/jquery-autocomplete-special-char-trigger

Comment: i will analyse the above link.But this example statically prefix all data using '@' symbol.otherwise I am not get proper idea.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from youre question, this could work:

```
$('#yourInput').on('change',function(){
    var input = $(this).val();
    var size = input.length;
    if(size > 0 && input[size-1] == '@'){
        $(this).val(input+autoCompleteText)
    }
});
```